# Formula to match two columns then return value in a third column if match

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formulas

The excel formula needs to match Column A and Column B if they are the same then display True on the same row as Column A if they match.

```
    A       B       C

1  Mustang   Camaro  True
2  Corvette  F150    False
3  Charger   Impala  False
4  Firebird  Mustang False
```

Comment: and what exactly have you actually tried? SO asks it's posters to show their effort. That said, a very simple google search will show you many ways to do this.

Comment: A more clear way of asking this may be "if the contents of the Cell in Column A matches anything in Column B, then display "True" in Column C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula is:

```
=COUNTIF($B$1:$B$4,A1)>0
```

[image]